# convert Millisecond to Date and Date to Millisecond

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert date to millisecond as per follow I converted.

`var d = new Date(1454911465467)  \\ output : Mon Feb 08 2016 11:34:25 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Now I want to convert using output to millisecond.

`var d = new Date('Mon Feb 08 2016 11:34:25 GMT+0530 (IST)').getTime()  \\output : 1454911465000`

`Expected output : 1454911465467`

Is their any way to convert these type of millisecond?

Comment: why aren't you just storing the `d` object? What is use case to need to convert to string then back to object? A simple `+d` will return same milliseconds

Comment: Or store original miiliseconds value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milliseconds are not specified in 'Mon Feb 08 2016 11:34:25 GMT+0530 (IST)'. The date precision here is down to seconds. Hence 467 milliseconds are missed in the second result.

You can check e.g.

```js
var originalDate = new Date(1454911465467);
var clonnedDate = new Date(originalDate.getFullYear(), originalDate.getMonth(), originalDate.getDate(), originalDate.getHours(), originalDate.getMinutes(), originalDate.getSeconds(), originalDate.getMilliseconds());
document.write(clonnedDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Much simpler: `var clonedDate = new Date(+originalDate)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG The author asked why milliseconds are missed. I explained him wehere he looses them and that the milliseconds can be got from the `Date` object.

Comment: Yes, but your method for copying a Date is vastly more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @RobG Your manner is nasty. The author is satisfied with the answer. I explained you why I used constructor with Date components (not copying constructor). What else do you need? You are the only who are not satisfied. But nobody is interested in your opinion.